# Visual Studio 2017 debug inspection not working anymore

Tags: c#

I used to be able to inspect the MenuItems property of my UWP NavigationView, but all of a sudden Visual Studio is telling me to enable native code debugging. What setting have I changed that caused this and how do I get it back? Super annoying!

Also, I've already tried resetting my Visual Studio settings, loaded symbols, and enabled symbol cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are still in debug mode and haven't changed the project to release, or any of the dependent projects to release.  Worth eliminating the obvious.

Comment: I wish it were something that simple. My configuration is set to Debug.